# AS3 and Movieclip dynamic resize handles

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am looking to add resize handles to a movieclip in flash AS3 so a user can click a corner and resize the movieclip. Does anyone have any sample code or an example I can follow? I cannot seem to find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the nice [Transform Tool 2](http://www.senocular.com/?entry=799) from senocular for starters.

It's very easy to implement. include it in the container movie clip & the same tool will be available over it's siblings inside that container. See the sample in the source.

There are some bugs, but this would be your best bet for now.

Others include :

1. [Transform Manager](http://blog.ryantan.net/2010/08/free-transform-manager/)
2. [Transform Tool from quiteless](http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/transform-tool-drag-scale-and-rotate-at-runtime/)

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I am looking for. Do you know of any other solutions? Thanks for the assistance!